# Python: Creating a function to time the execution of each of the algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm

Three different algorithms defined as below:

```
def alg1 (a, b)
  #body

def alg2 (c, d)
  #body

def alg3 (e, f)
  #body
```

We want the time function to do the following:

```
def timefunc (s1, s2)

    #Start the clock

    #Call one of your algorithms

    #Stop the clock

    #Print the answer and time it took
```

I did this but it's not working:

```
from datetime import datetime 

def timefunc (s1, s2):
   startTime1= datetime.now() 
   alg1(s1, s2)
   timeElapsed1=datetime.now()-startTime1
   print('Time elpased for alg1 '.format(timeElapsed1)) 

   startTime2= datetime.now() 
   alg2(s1,s2)
   timeElapsed2=datetime.now()-startTime2 
   print('Time elpased for alg2 '.format(timeElapsed2)) 

   startTime3= datetime.now() 
   alg3(s1,s2)
   timeElapsed3=datetime.now()-startTime3 
   print('Time elpased for alg3 '.format(timeElapsed3))
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or if you have a better way of doing this. Thank you.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel instead of  using the `timeit` or `time` modules?

Comment: How is it not working? What output is it giving? What output are you expecting? You should post a [mcve].

Comment: If you can show us the error atleast

Comment: Use `time.time()` for start time and end time

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time.time()` from `time`module.